# How to set variable value in bootstrap popover using content & setcontent?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, popover, bootstrap-popover

```
   <script>
     function showData(recId,e)
        {  
      Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction('{!$RemoteAction.ControllerClass.getPopData}',

              recId,"{!record.Id}",

              function (result, event) {

              if(event.status)

              alert(result);   //Alerts correct value        

              $('.li').popover({content:result}); //Holds previous value 

              }, {buffer:false}
            );     
        }   
 </script>
```

Now the problem I am facing is if there are 3 items in the list displayed the first one I click the correct data is displayed but clicking on any other item shows same previous data until I refresh page and click. However in remoteaction I can see the correct data is fetched each time but in page it always shows the first item I click.

Alert shows the correct updated content but popover doesn't set the same in box.

I have also tried the below way which I found in one of the answers using `setcontent`. This works somewhat but I have to click twice to get the correct content. In first onclick it shows the previous value :

```
   $('.li').popover({    
    content: 'Loading...'    
     });
       
     $('.li').attr('data-content', res);
 var popover = $('.li').data('popover');
 popover.setContent();
 popover.$tip.addClass(popover.options.placement);
```

Any idea how can I fix this?

Updated based on comments. It does the almost work but when I click one after another item but if I mouseout and mouseover on same item it fails to display popover even though I can see the remoteaction call happens.

```
    <script>
    function showPopup(recId,e)
  {  

    var res='';

    Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction('{!$RemoteAction.ControllerClass.getData}',
        recId,"{!record.Id}",
        function (result, event) {
        if(event.status)
          res=result;
        $('.li').popover("destroy").popover({content:res, placement: "bottom", template: '<div class="popover" style="width:250px; font-size:12px"><div class="arrow"></div><div class="popover-inner"><h3 class="popover-title"></h3><div class="popover-content"><p></p></div></div></div>'

                 });
        },{ buffer: false}

      );     

  }

</script>
```

Comment: The `content` parameter can also be a `function()` which may be a better option for retrieving dynamic content.

Comment: I'm using a function and passing parameters to that. Not sure how to write nested functions here.

Comment: reverse it: `popover(po_options)` where `var po_options = { ... content: function(){ //retrieve data }, ... }`

Comment: or retrieve the data in the `show.bs.popover` event : `$('#myPopover').on('show.bs.popover', function () {
  // do something…
})`

Comment: I can see the remote calls made but unable to set the content. I have added script in last section. Can you please check once. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

Given a basic popover per BS3 docs you have:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary li" 
    title="Popover title" >
    Click to toggle popover
</button>
```

With `<script>`:

```
// Where the `html` property is true or false 
// if your returned dynamic data is 
// html or simple text respectively.

var po_options = { 
  html    : true, 
  content : function() {

               // $(this) is set to the element with the popover
               // get your_data, 

               return your_data;
            }
};
```

And initialize by:

```
 $('.li').popover(po_options);
```

---

In this snippet you can see the popovers appear with returned content.  All you should need to do is pass appropriate parameters depending on which `.li` is clicked and pass it your data retrieval code and you should be good to go

```js
var po_options = {
  html: true,
  content: function() {
    var p1 = $(this).data("param1");
    return '<span>' + p1 + '</span>';
  }
};


$('.li').popover(po_options);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary li" title="Popover 1" data-param1="Parameter1">
        Click to toggle popover 1
</button>
<br />
<br />
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary li" title="Popover 2" data-param1="Parameter2">
        Click to toggle popover 2
</button>
```

---

#### Addendum

Not quite right. My example above is intended to show information taken from data attributes from the clicked buttons and was intended to show you one way to pass parameters to the tooltip content handler

Consider the following instead:

I assume all your popup buttons are marked with the `.li` class so initialize the popovers like this:

```
 $('.li').popover(po_options);
```

Where `po_options` is defined as

```
var po_options = { 
  html    : true, 
  content : function() {
    var p1 = 'Loading...';

    Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
      '{!$RemoteAction.ControllerClass.getData}',
       recId,"{!record.Id}",
       function (result, event) {
         if(event.status) {
           p1 = result; 
         }
      });

      return p1;
    }
};
```

Now there are a few things to consider:

1. If that call succeeds, what is in `result`?
2. Is the call to `invokeAction` blocking or non-blocking, that is synchronous or asynchronous?

**Item #2 is very important.**

If the call is synchronous  you should be fine, assuming `result` is html text.

But if the call is asynchronous, your not likely to see tooltip content because the `po_options.content` handler will likely return before invokeAction parameter `result` gets a value.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I tried the script as updated in question (the last one) but it doesn't set any data in content. Please can you help? Thanks

Comment: Yes, It works asynchronously. I tried the snip but it didn't make the remote call, however I am close to my requirement with the updated script (last one). Only issue is that on same list item if I mouseover back it doesn't show popover. Again I have to mouseout and mouseover then it shows popover.  If I do on different items it works fine.

Comment: That might be just a matter of how the popover is setup, by default tooltips are mouseover, and popovers, which are based on the same code, are click driven. but I believe it is configureable.  Perhaps handle the call in the popover show event `show.bs.popover`. Just fyi it's end of day here so I'm out until tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time! I will try few options again. It's 03.10am and I'm struggling with this badly.

Comment: I tried the solutions but it seems var is not set because callback function behaves asynchronously (if i set any other data it works). 
Now I tried adding a wait time before creating tooltip but it didn't work.
only way it works is inverse of the solution you gave. unfortunately it does not work with trigger: hover. It works with click only. I guess this is because of async remote action. As onmouseover & click have gap always so data is ready by the time.

Comment: then use the `click` to make the async call and in the callback function manually show the popover with `$(elem).popover('show')` where `elem` is a reference to the correct popover.

Comment: Problem is <li> is wrapped in a <repeat> tag which creates multiple <li> based on data returned from controller and if I use show then it shows tooltip at each item. I am unable to figure out how to distinguish each.

Comment: you should have a way to set an `id` for each `li`, ie: `id="li1"` to `id="liN"` or set appropriate `data-` attributes so you can determine which li was clicked such that `$(elem)` in my previous comment is a single, unique `li`